# Python Typing: Should i add type annotations for __slots__ in my class?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a question concerning typing within python.

***Warning**: this question isn't a duplicate of `__slots__ type annotations for Python / PyCharm` because the subject is about the utility and is not a pycharm problem, howerver as you may see, it is one of the pros i mentioned later on.*

---

To starts with, i have a  class `Collections` to group all my collection from my main db (mongo db database):

```py
class Collections(StaticClassList):
    """A class to group all mongo collections from main database."""
    __slots__: Tuple[str, ...] = (
        "plugins", "prefixes", "reaction_roles", "welcome", "verify",
        "chatbot", "chatbot", "permissions"
    )

collections: Collections = Collections(database.axiol)
```

Which inherit from this class:

```py
class StaticClassList(ABC):
    __instances = set()

    def __init__(self, base) -> None:
        ...

        for attr_name in self.__slots__:
            setattr(
                self, attr_name,
                base['_'.join(map(str.capitalize, attr_name.split()))]
            )

    ...
```

***Quick Note**: this abstract class is used by multiples classes and the __init__ method as been reduced to necessary minimum which is the reasons of the two `...`*

---

my question is whether i should add theses type annotations as below:

```
. class Collections(StaticClassList):
.     """A class to group all mongo collections from main database."""
.     __slots__: Tuple[str, ...] = (
.         "plugins", "prefixes", "reaction_roles", "welcome", "verify",
.         "chatbot", "chatbot", "permissions"
.     )
. 
+     plugins: AsyncIOMotorCollection
+     prefixes: AsyncIOMotorCollection
+     reaction_roles: AsyncIOMotorCollection
+     welcome: AsyncIOMotorCollection
+     verify: AsyncIOMotorCollection
+     chatbot: AsyncIOMotorCollection
+     permissions: AsyncIOMotorCollection
.
```

*This is a diff to show what this would adds.*

---

Those are my pro & cons for annotations

`pros`

- It's not evident that each slots are instances of `AsyncIOMotorCollection` and *"Explicit is better than implicit."* (Zen Of Python)
- It allows for the ide to detect the attributes (which are not annotated otherwise, but is that a huge deal?)

`cons`

- It requires me to import `AsyncIOMotorCollection` from `motor.motor_asyncio` and `AsyncIOMotorCollection` is not declared in __all__
- It makes the class looks way more clunky, and i've created `StaticClassList` to avoid writting something like this:

  ```py
      # <Collections>
      plugins: AsyncIOMotorCollection = database.axiol["Plugins"]
      prefixes: AsyncIOMotorCollection = database.axiol["Prefixes"]
      reaction_roles: AsyncIOMotorCollection = database.axiol["Reaction Roles"]
      ...
  ```

---

*I hope you will be able to help me solve this interrogation,
Have a nice day all!*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This kind of thing is considered off topic here because it's subjective. For my own opinion, I think we have already left the world of `simple is better than complex; complex is better than complicated` once we have decided to use both `__slots__` and type annotations. If you want a language that checks types at compile time, use one. There even exist ones that can do type inference and don't require manifest typing.

Comment: Thanks, but typing module less for checking types at compile time than to allow help understanding types involved, right? Almost Python is my main language and wouldn't to make this project within an other one ^^.

Comment: Like I said, it's a matter of opinion, which is exactly why we don't like questions like this here. You might have better luck on a *discussion forum*, such as you might find on Reddit or Quora.

Comment: I am sincerely sorry for that then, though to had made everything properly for my first question, but seems like i missed important point. Will take that in note for my futures questions and hopefully don't makes that mistake again !

Comment: For reference, please see [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Comment: Will takes a look, again, sorry for my imprudence

Comment: Once you have 20 pr you have access to the chat, https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An answer by `ichard26` (who unfortunately dont have a stack overflow account)*

---

I'd type the attributes so my IDE or other tooling could perform more useful checks against my code that uses these attributes.

Let's say I have this code:

```py
# let's just assume this is an invalid operation
val = collections.welcome[1]
```

mypy without the type annotations probably wouldn't catch this issue OR would complain that a valid operation isn't so
since how these attributes are defined is so dynamic that it has no choice but to assume Any for them

> - *It requires me to import AsyncIOMotorCollection from motor.motor_asyncio and AsyncIOMotorCollection is not declared in all*

This one could be resolved via `from __future__ import annotations` + `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING: from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorCollection.`

> - *It makes the class looks way more clunky, and i've created StaticClassList to avoid writting something like this:*

Yeah there's no way working around this con, it's the price of dynamically setattr-ing the attributes. For me the tooling is worth the extra lines but that's your call.

---

The annotations future flag causes the annotations to stay as strings and are never evaluated unless Python is specifically asked to
and adding that with the typing.TYPE_CHECKING constant (which is False but assumed True by type checkers) means the import effectively doesn't exist (other than visually)
only a Python 3.7+ thing tho